# What is this Oracle regexp matching in this production code?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Here's the code that is in production:

```
dynamic_sql := q'[ with cte as
               select user_id,
                      user_name
               from   user_table
               where  regexp_like (bizz_buzz,'^[^Z][^Y6]]' || q'[') AND
                      user_code not in ('A','E','I')
               order by 1]';
```

1. Start at the beginning and search bizz_buzz
2. Match any one character that is NOT Z
3. Match any two characters that are not Y6
4. What's the ']' after the 6?
5. Then what?

Comment: Something's missing. The `q'['` construct is known as an alternate quoting mechanism used when quoting a string that contains quotes and would normally look like this:  `select q'[this isn't mine, it's yours]' from dual;`.  It seems to be missing the closing part and this will error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that StackOverflow's formatting is causing some of the confusion in the answers.  Oracle has a syntax for a string literal, `q'[...]'`, which means that the `...` portion is to be interpreted exactly as-is; so for instance it can include single quotes without having to escape each one individually.

But the code formatting here doesn't understand that syntax, so it is treating each single-quote as a string delimiter, which makes the result look different that how Oracle really sees it.

The expression is concatenating two such string literals together.  (I'm not sure why - it looks like it would be possible to write this as a single string literal with no issues.)  As pointed out in another answer/comment, the resulting SQL string is actually:

```
with cte as
           select user_id,
                  user_name
           from   user_table
           where  regexp_like (bizz_buzz,'^[^Z][^Y6]') AND
                  user_code not in ('A','E','I')
           order by 1
```

And also as pointed out in another answer, the `[^Y6]` portion of the regex matches a single character, not two.  So this expression should simply match any string whose first character is not 'Z' and whose second character is neither 'Y' nor '6'.

Comment: This post summarizes all the other discoveries nicely and ends up answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

When not in couples `]` means... Well... Itself:

```
^[^Z][^Y6]]/

^ assert position at start of the string
[^Z] match a single character not present in the list below
    Z the literal character Z (case sensitive)
[^Y6] match a single character not present in the list below
    Y6 a single character in the list Y6 literally (case sensitive)
] matches the character ] literally
```

1. Start at the beginning and search bizz_buzz
2. Match any one character that is NOT Z
3. Match any <strike>two</strike> one characters that is not Y or 6
4. What's the ']' after the 6? it's a `]`

Comment: But what does ` || q'['` mean? (see `5.` in the question)

Comment: @Thomas, you'd be right if the `]` was really part of the regex - but it's not, as indicated by Gary_W's answer/comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I have to post this here as the comment section is inappropriate for the formatting required.  After your edit above that shows the entire statement, I ran this to see what the string ends up being:

```
select q'[ with cte as
               select user_id,
                      user_name
               from   user_table
               where  regexp_like (bizz_buzz,'^[^Z][^Y6]]' || q'[') AND
                      user_code not in ('A','E','I')
               order by 1]' txt
from dual;
```

It ended up yielding this:

```
with cte as
               select user_id,
                      user_name
               from   user_table
               where  regexp_like (bizz_buzz,'^[^Z][^Y6]') AND
                      user_code not in ('A','E','I')
               order by 1
```

It is apparent now that the closing bracket and quote at the end of the regex belong to the first alternate quote string and not to the regex.  This is concatenating 2 alternate quoted strings which is a tad confusing as it sure looked like part of the regex.  If anything you are learning the importance of comments for the poor person behind you!  Please comment this accordingly when you are done figuring this out.  Even include a link to this post.

Comment: Wow, it appears the || 'q[' is how programmer continued the dynamic query, no?

Comment: Ah.. I see now, the `dynamic_sql`  variable is becoming a series of concatenated strings that are defined by q'['....

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see before the closing bracket and quote at the end of the regex really belongs to the end of the first alternate quote string and not to the regex.  whoever gave me that vote should take it away lol

Comment: I voted it because I just learned how to run my  q'[' query through dual to see what it yielded. That was very useful.